# Of what is this version of?

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to debug an application running in embedded linux. The application uses qt-mobility.

On my PC, it works fine, but not on my device.

When I start my application, I get this message in the /var/log/messages :

```
Nov  3 11:45:41 pdm360ng daemon.info bluetoothd[1435]: Discovery session 0x1074aab0 with :1.1 activated
```

On my PC (running ubuntu 14.04), /var/log/syslog tells :

```
Nov  3 11:01:15 deeclu42 bluetoothd[25182]: Discovery session 0x7f0897203160 with :1.599 activated
```

So, it prints a version of something (1.1 for embedded, and 1.599 for my PC), and different version may cause problems I am seeing.

The bluetoothd is of the same version in both cases :

```
bluetoothd --version
4.101
```

So, what is printing that version in the log?

Comment: Not a version, just a unique, random ID for the sender on dbus.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the `1.1` and `1.599`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ok, thanks. It makes sense. It does increase every time I start my program